# How to translate minimization problem containing a min function into a Mixed Integer Problem (MIP)?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following optimization problem:

$\min J = \sum_{i=0}^{N} k_i = k_0 + k_1 +\dots+ k_N$

s.t:

$k_i = f_i(z_i)$
where
$f_i(x) = \begin{cases}
    x,& \text{if } x\leq P_i\\
    P_i,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} = \min(x, P_i)$

and $z_i$ is a linear combination of other constants and decision variables $z_i = \sum_{j=0}^{M} K_{ij}(Y_{ij} - y_{ij})$

- $P_i >0, \, K_{ij}>0, Y_{ij}>0$ are constants
- $y_{ij} \geq 0,\, k_i \geq 0$ are continuous decision variables

I do not know how to write the minimization problem containing the Objective with the summation over min functions into a Mixed Integer programming problem suitable for Pythons pulp package for example.
I do not have a mathematics background and did my research for many days on this topic, reading papers or articles, but it is difficult to correctly identify the problem when not coming from a mathematics background.

Does anyone know how to solve this and/or how to translate this into a MIP formulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to minimize
$$\sum_{i=0}^N \min\left(\sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}(Y_{ij}-y_{ij}), P_i\right).$$
Introduce a continuous variable $s_i$ to represent the outer summand and a binary variable $b_i$ to indicate which minimand is active.
Let $M^1_i$ be a small constant upper bound on $\sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}(Y_{ij}-y_{ij}) - s_i$,
and let $M^2_i$ be a small constant upper bound on $P_i - s_i$.
The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=0}^N s_i$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
s_i &\le \sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}(Y_{ij}-y_{ij}) \tag1 \\
s_i &\le P_i \tag2 \\
s_i &\ge \sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}(Y_{ij}-y_{ij}) - M^1_i b_i \tag3 \\
s_i &\ge P_i - M^2_i (1-b_i) \tag4 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $b_i=0 \implies s_i \ge \sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}(Y_{ij}-y_{ij})$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $b_i=1 \implies s_i \ge P_i$.

---

Given $0 \le y_{ij} \le Y_{ij}$, you can take
$$M^1_i = \sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}(Y_{ij}-0) - P_i = \sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}Y_{ij} - P_i$$
and
$$M^2_i = P_i - \sum_{j=0}^M K_{ij}(Y_{ij}-Y_{ij}) = P_i.$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will try and implement this approach. How do you have to choose the $M_i^1$ and $M_i^2$ values?

Comment: Do you have a good upper bound on $y_{ij}$?

Comment: Yes, it is $Y_{ij} - y_{ij} \geq 0$, so the upper bound is $y_{ij} \leq Y_{ij}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answers! This makes so much sense now. I have another question about the constants: Can i choose any constant as long as it does fit with the whole system, e.g. icould also choose $M_i^1$ to be $M_i^{1} = \sum_{j=0}^{M} K_{ij}Y_{ij}$, is that correct?

Comment: You can choose a larger value than what I recommended, but doing so will weaken the strength of the linear programming relaxation.

Comment: And the binary decision variables $b_i$ are optimized to indicate the active minimand - Why does this happen? Why are they going to have the correct values after optimization? This is the only thing i cannot grasp at the Moment, it feels like magic (but surely it is not)

Comment: @MarkusU The solver will explore a binary decision tree, where at each node a binary variable $b_i$ will be selected and two child nodes will be created, one with $b_i=0$ and the other with $b_i=1$. (3) and (4) will then assert one choice for minimand in each of the children, and that selection remains in force for the subtree descending from the child node. So the decisions are the values of the $b_i$, and activation of the correct minimands is the consequence of those decisions, rather than the other way round (selecting the minimands and getting the binary values as consequences).

Comment: @RobPratt I implemented the solution and it worked. But I have another constraint, that makes the solution infeasible. I want to implement and add the additional constraint $\sum_{i=0}^{N} y_{ij} = S_j$ with $S_j$ being  supply values. How can i include this to be optimal? It seems like the additional constraint and $y_{ij} \leq Y_{ij}$ is not possible for the solver to be both true.

Comment: To help diagnose the issue, I recommend solving with a constant zero objective function, with your new constraints, and without (1) through (4).